# How can I still get my core dump when I run something from cron which would normally core?

Tags: c++, c, unix, cron, coredump

Today something which I cron and for which I try to detect core dumps and alert me did in fact hit a false assertion (something which normally core dumps it when I run it on the commandline either foreground or background) but no core was dumped. I wrote this simple test:

```
int main
{
sleep(3);
assert(false);
}
```

which when I compile and run will core dump all the time. But when I put it on the crontab, i instead got an email from the cron daemon saying:

```
rocket: main.cpp:10: int main(int, char**): Assertion `false' failed.
/bin/sh: line 1: 32448 Aborted                 ./rocket
```

and no core file was ever placed in `/cores`. Why is this and how can I get my core?

Comment: Which operating system is this? Why do you expect something would be put in /cores? (I don't have /cores on any of my Linux systems)

Comment: It is Red Hat linux. It must have been configured to do this I guess. Good observation though..the working directory did not have the core file either though...does cron have a place to put cores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a core file to be generated on a crash, core dumps must be enabled in the current environment. From a shell, this can be done using ulimit:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Which means "set the maximum core dump size to unlimited". Your system is probably configured to do this in interactive shells, but not in cron jobs. To do it from a cron job, you need to modify this limit. If the cron job is a shell script which calls other programs, you can just call `ulimit` as above. On the other hand, if the job is an executable, you can create a wrapper to run it with:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -c unlimited
exec "$@"
```

Another option is to modify the program to set the limit itself using the [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) function.

As to why your cores are going in /cores as opposed to the working directory: your distribution may have adjusted the [core pattern](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html), possibly using a program to handle core files and place them in /cores.